# Counter name of inline lists with enumitem

Tags: numbering, lists, counters, enumitem

I am using the `enumitem` package and need to access the counter values after the end of the environment. With a standard

```
\newlist{Example}{enumerate}{2}
```

for instance, the counter value is simply the list name with an `i` appended to the end: `Examplei`.

What is the counter name when an inline list is declared, such as

```
\newlist{Example*}{enumerate*}{2}%
```

The value highlighted in red is incorrect and should be `2`:

[image]

### Notes:

- Ideally, I would prefer to have the inline version use the same counter as the non-inline version. But a solution just accessing the inline counter might be useful for others who come across this question.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newlist{Example}{enumerate}{2}%
\setlist[Example]{label={\arabic*.}}

\newlist{Example*}{enumerate*}{2}%
\setlist[Example*]{itemjoin={\hspace*{2.0em}}, label={\arabic*.}}


\begin{document}
\textbf{Vertical List}
\begin{Example}
    \item First V item.
    \item Second V item.
    \item Third V item.
\end{Example}

There were \arabic{Examplei} elements in prior list.

\bigskip
\textbf{Horizontal List}:
\begin{Example*}
    \item First H item.
    \item Second H item.
\end{Example*}

\medskip
%% How do I get the correct count here?
There were \textcolor{red}{\arabic{Examplei}} elements in prior list.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `Example*i`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newlist{Example}{enumerate}{2}%
\setlist[Example]{label={\arabic*.}}

\newlist{Example*}{enumerate*}{2}%
\setlist[Example*]{itemjoin={\hspace*{2.0em}}, label={\arabic*.}}


\begin{document}
\textbf{Vertical List}
\begin{Example}
    \item First V item.
    \item Second V item.
    \item Third V item.
\end{Example}

There were \arabic{Examplei} elements in prior list.

\bigskip
\textbf{Horizontal List}:
\begin{Example*}
    \item First H item.
    \item Second H item.
\end{Example*}

\medskip
%% How do I get the correct count here?
There were \textcolor{red}{\arabic{Example*i}} elements in prior list.

\end{document}
```

If you wish for the inline enumeration `Example*` to use the same counter as `Example`, you can add

```
\makeatletter
\expandafter\let\csname c@Example*i\endcsname\c@Examplei
\makeatother
```

to your preamble after defining both lists.

Comment: What if we didn't use `newlist` and used `enumerate*` directly? What would the counter name be?

Comment: @RaffiKhatchadourian: The counter used within `enumerate*` (when you load `\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}` is `enumi` (see the value when you print `\theenumi`).